# Как реализовать в программе соединение android устройства и сервера через WiFi

Tags: c#, android, wifi

Привет, я абсолютный новичок в программировании (немного в C# понимаю) и надеюсь на хоть какую то помощь. У меня есть цель написать программу (суть её вам не важна) которая будет считывать например одну строку в текстовом файле и в зависимости от содержимого выполнять определенные действия. Ничего особенно сложного в этом нет, но вот только текстовый файл который будем читать находится не на устройстве, а на сервере (с адресом `\\10.29.76.10` ,ну или компьютере с немного другим адресом). Проблема в том что я не понимаю как реализовать программно соединение устройства с сервером через `WiFi`. Например, если проделывать это вручную (к примеру с помощью программы ES Проводник), то проблем не возникает. Моего скудного опыта и понимания, а тем более знания не хватает для этой задачи, поэтому прошу помощи у знающих. Буду благодарен любой подсказки и помощи.

Comment: developers.android.com

Comment: "Привет, я абсолютный новичок в физике, я не хочу ничего читать, объясните мне, пожалуйста, как построить реактор для управляемого термоядерного синтеза. Проблема в том, что моих знаний в физике не хватает для этого, а знаю я только первый закон Ньютона"

Comment: апплодисменты этому господину

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если тебе нужно читать текст с сервера то можно преобразовывать его допустим в json и конектиться к удаленному серверу функциями которые есть в андроид сдк.

Думаю [вот эта](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) статья тебе идеально подходит

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы, буду разбираться)))

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю, нужно написать приложение на андроид, которое будет подключиться к определенному адресу, считывать текстовый файл с настройками и что-то делать. Тогда можно воспользоваться чем то вроде этого:

```
public static InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return stream;
    }
```

И еще, не забудь, что все это нужно делать на отдельном потоке. При помощи AsyncTask например. Оно как раз сюда подходит. Вот [первый](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html) из серии уроков про AsyncTask. Суть проста: в методе doInBackground мы грузим данные из сети и обрабатываем их. Получив необходимую информацию из текстового файла в том виде, в котором мы хотели её получить (какой либо объект содержащий нашу информацию) мы возвращаем этот объект из doInBackground. Далее он попадает в onPostExecute. Вот тут то мы и выполняем работу с нашим полученным объектом.